# using workespace and esbuild in angular 16

Tags: workspace, angular-library, esbuild, angular16

I have created an angular project with the following structure:

[image]

I have two applications and a library in my project

my problem is when I config angular.json to use **esbuild**  as shown below:
[image]

after running the project, any changes in **easylib** dose not detect at runtime